# how do I connect to wss socket with vue-socket.io?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, socket.io, wss

I am trying to connect with wss but wss keep replacing with https

My socket config is

```
        import Vue from 'vue';
        import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io';
        import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
        import store from '../store';

        export default async (/* { app, router, Vue ... } */) => {
          Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
            debug: true,
            connection: io('wss://echo.websocket.org'),
            vuex: {
              store,
              actionPrefix: 'SOCKET_',
              mutationPrefix: 'SOCKET_',
            },
          }));
        };
```

I get below error :

[image: error]

Comment: does test.betbox.me belong to you?  socket.io connects using longpoll first, and then upgrades the connection to wss, and the longpoll (an XHR request) requires CORS headers to connect cross domain

Comment: You can use this so that it only tries to use websockets: io('wss://echo.websocket.org',{transports: ['websocket']})

Comment: @user120242 thank you so much,
I changed the connection, but I need to remove "?EIO=3&transport=websocket" from the URL, how can I do that?

Comment: new connection:

const options = { transports: ['websocket'], path: '/fariborz/12345678' };
export default async (/* { app, router, Vue ... } */) => {
  Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
    debug: true,
    connection: io('wss://test.betbox.me:2083',options),
    vuex: {
      store,
      actionPrefix: 'SOCKET_',
      mutationPrefix: 'SOCKET_',
    },
  }));
};
@user120242